# Javascript loop images

Tags: javascript

My HTML has 5 images of lightOff.jpg bulbs + 1 button.

My mission is to press a button and then turn on the lights (change the images to lightOn.jpg) one by one every of 1 second. Meaning 1 bulb will on and after 1 second the next bulb will on and so on….
This is what I try to start….

```js
function turnOnLights() {
  var bulb = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
  for (var i = 0; i < bulb.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById(bulb[i]).src = "https://maxcdn.icons8.com/app/uploads/2015/12/light_on-1.png"
    }, 1000);

  }
};
```

```css
#containger {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="containger">

  <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/app/uploads/2015/12/light_off-1.png" id="one">
  <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/app/uploads/2015/12/light_off-1.png" id="two">
  <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/app/uploads/2015/12/light_off-1.png" id="three">
  <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/app/uploads/2015/12/light_off-1.png" id="four">

  <br>

  <button type="button" onclick="turnOnLights();">Click to turn on lights</button>





</div>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Also, you need to set the timeout to `1000*i`. Otherwise they all switch on after one second.

Comment: I created a snippet for you with images to show you how to format your code into a [mcve]

Comment: The code you want is `for (var i = 0; i < bulb.length; i++) {
    (function(index){
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(bulb[index]).src = "lightOn.jpg"
      }, 1000*index);
    })(i);`